# Filtering in django admin using address bar

Tags: django, django-admin

Suppose I have a model Order, which has a column num -- an order number. Now I want to filter several rows from this model in admin view. Having 1 value, I do:

```
http://bla-bla-bla/admin/app/order/?num__exact=11534
```

How can I do this when I have several values?

Or should I use queryset()? How then I should send a list of values to request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` should work, try this in the url

```
http://bla-bla-bla/admin/app/order/?num__in=11534,11535,11536
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need! And how simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that whatever you put in the query string has to be allowed for the admin interface. You can't put in filters that weren't defined there - ever since this security release https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2010/dec/22/security/

Comment: Thank you too. In my case there is no cross-relational lookups.